# How to use UIVisualEffectView with Objective-C

Tags: ios8, uiimageview, uivisualeffectview

I've been looking for documentation on how to use the UIVisualEffectView with Objective-C in iOS8.

I've seen some code examples but would appreciate the steps to use the actual view in the Object Library. This is what I tried, which had no effect:

1. Create a new storyboard scene
2. Add a UIVisualEffectView
3. Add a UIImageView
4. Add a picture to the UIImageView

I want to have a blurred picture as the background for my scenes. Can someone point me to a tutorial or provide instructions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a demo which demonstrates using `UIVisualEffectView` with **vibrancy** and also with **vibrancy & blur**. It uses a little bit different way of implementing via storyboard so look at https://github.com/Vaberer/BlurTransition.